# Leetcode - ReorderList. Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python

I was trying to do this question where I have to error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' at the last while loop.

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def reorderList(self, head):
        if head.next == None:
            return head
        slowPointer, fastPointer = head, head.next.next

        while fastPointer and fastPointer.next:
            slowPointer = slowPointer.next
            fastPointer = fastPointer.next.next
        
        tmpPointer = slowPointer
        secondPointer =slowPointer.next
        tmpPointer.next = None

        ## reverse second List
        prev = None
        while secondPointer:
            tmp = secondPointer.next
            secondPointer.next = prev
            prev = secondPointer
            secondPointer = tmp
        
   
        LP, RP = head, prev
     
        ## out of loop when both reaches None
        while RP:
            tmpLP, tmpRP = LP.next, RP.next
            LP.next = RP
            RP.next = tmpLP
            
            LP = tmpLP
            RP = tmpRP

        return head
```

I'm unsure why.

I was expecting it to run per normal.

Comment: `RP` is not `None`, but `LP` might be.

Comment: how are you instantiating this ?  it takes a object which needs the property next...

Comment: that is where the beauty of the debugger will help you, we are not your debugger

Comment: if it is not running normal most of the time you made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

`LP` is None in case you have an odd number of elements in the linked list. For example [1,2,3,4,5].

Consider what happens when at the start of your `while` loop you have:

`LP=Data(val=1, next=Data(val=2, next=None))`

and

`RP=Data(val=5, next=Data(val=4, next=Data(val=3, next=None)))`

I guess the correct approach would be to advance `RP=RP.next` in such cases.